# How to convert Prefix to Infix

Tags: java, infix-notation

I'm really struggling to understand the whole concept of converting Prefix expressions to Infix expressions.

With an expression of `Prefix: -4/+1*327`, would that convert to `4-1+3*2/7`?

Another example maybe `Prefix: +-a*bc/de`, would that convert to `a-b*c+d/e`?

Is there some sort of algorithm to make this simpler?

Comment: Wikipedia gives you pseudocode using a stack.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation

Comment: How would you convert it by hand?

Comment: `-4/+1*327` -> `4-(1+3*2)/7`.  `+-abc/de` is an invalid expression.

Comment: @saka1029 sorry, it should be +-a*bc/de

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public class Prefix {

    static final Map<String, Integer> PREC = new HashMap<>();
    static { PREC.put("+", 1); PREC.put("-", 1); PREC.put("*", 2); PREC.put("/", 2); }

    static class Source {
        final String s;
        Source(String s) { this.s = s; }
        int index = 0;
        String token;
        String next() { return token = index >= s.length() ? null : s.substring(index, ++index); }
    }

    static String parse(String s) { return parse(new Source(s), 0); }

    static String parse(Source t, int prec) {
        Integer self = PREC.get(t.next());
        if (self != null) {
            String op = t.token;
            String result = String.format("%s%s%s",parse(t, self), op, parse(t, self));
            if (self < prec) result = "(" + result + ")";
            return result;
        } else
            return t.token;
    }

    static void test(String prefix) { System.out.println(prefix + " -> " + parse(prefix)); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("-4/+1*327");
        test("+-a*bc/de");
        test("*-ab+cd");
    }
}
```

result:

```
-4/+1*327 -> 4-(1+3*2)/7
+-a*bc/de -> a-b*c+d/e
*-ab+cd -> (a-b)*(c+d)
```